# HortonWorks Hadoop Sandbox and Tableau

Tags: hadoop, tableau-api, hortonworks-data-platform

I am attempting to connect Tableau to the HortonWorks Hadoop sandbox as described here:  http://hortonworks.com/kb/how-to-connect-tableau-to-hortonworks-sandbox/ 
Tableau is able to see the virtual server as a data source, and it accurately lists the available Schemas and Tables.

However, when attempting to select any table or preview it's data, it displays an error popup that `'An error has occurred while loading the data. No such table [default].[tablename]'` where default is the schema and tablename is the name of the table I'm attempting to view.

Here is what comes back when I run **ifconfig** from the Terminal window in the vm sandbox.  Tableau is connecting to the vm via **192.168.50.128**.

```
eth3      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0C:29:EB:B9:DC  
          inet addr:192.168.50.128  Bcast:192.168.50.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::20c:29ff:feeb:b9dc/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:42011 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:9750 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:15123871 (14.4 MiB)  TX bytes:4019795 (3.8 MiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:5185579 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:5185579 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:2054785522 (1.9 GiB)  TX bytes:2054785522 (1.9 GiB)
```

The guide states `Enter the IP address of the Sandbox VM (typically 192.168.56.101)`  which is different.

Is this IP difference the source of the issue or is there something else I've overlooked?  Im assuming that since it can see the schema and tables that this wouldn't matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out this was a permissions issue which I was able to resolve by following this guide:  http://diveintobigdata.blogspot.com/2015/10/error-occurred-executing-hive-query.html

However, everywhere I was told to input localhost, such as when accessing Ambari, I had to replace localhost with 192.168.50.128 which I mentioned above is the IP I saw when executing ifconfig in the terminal.

Also, in step 1 of the guide there should not be any spaces in the file paths that were provided.